# How do I determine if a directory is part of a Subversion working copy?

Tags: svn

I have a script that copies some files into a project.  Such a project is usually a Subversion working copy, but not always.  If it is a working copy, I want to add the files to Subversion automatically.  But how do I know that the directory is part of a Subversion working copy?  So far I checked for a .svn sub-folder, but that doesn't work with Subversion 1.7.  I just need to know if `svn add files...` will work, no other data needs to be extracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the svn info property and then pipe to just get the url as follows:

```
svn info -R | FIND "URL:" >urlText
```

then load this output into another variable and you could work with it like:

```
set /p urlRepo= <urlText
del urlText
```

Comment: I don't need the URL.  At least `svn info` gives a non-zero exit status if it is not a working copy.  But is that exit status reliable?

Comment: that was just an example.. just pick any of those properties.. it shoud be fine

Comment: So the idea is to parse for a string that exists only if it is a working copy, e.g. "^URL:".  The option `-R` is not needed in that case.

Answer (score 4):

Just run `svn status`. You'll get a message like the following if the it's not a working copy:

```
svn: warning: '.' is not a working copy
```

**Edit:** If you are concerned about the recursive nature of `svn status` you can limit the depth by (depending on the version of the client) either

```
svn status --depth=empty
```

or

```
svn status --non-recusive
```

(The latter format is listed as *obsolete* in recent versions of the client).

Comment: `svn status` is not a good idea because it is a recursive operation that might take some time.  I would need to test what the right non-recursive option is.  The message might be in a different language, which makes it difficult to parse.

Comment: @user909066 - I've added some information regarding a non-recursive option.

Comment: `--depth=empty` returns `A       .` in my test case.  This is not an empty string.  An older client returns `svn: invalid option: --depth=empty`.  I prefer a more portable solution.

Comment: @user909066 - Interesting, I ran several test cases and never got a string returned from `--depth=empty`; I'll updated the text.  As regards compatibility, and as noted in the text, there was a move from the (now obsolete) `--non-recursive` to the more functionality `--depth=...`.

Comment: The --xml option to svn is meant to shield the user from differences in the output, like a different locale.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a script so... solution in script form :)

```
 REPO="http://repository_url"
 WCDIR="dir_you_are_checking"
 WCBRANCH=`svn info ${WCDIR} 2> /dev/null | grep "^URL:" | cut -d" " -f2 | sed s,${REPO}/,,`
 if [ -z "${WCBRANCH}" ]
 then
   echo "Error: directory ${WCDIR} exists and is not part of a working copy."
   exit 1
 fi
 # WCBRANCH will contain the WCDIR path inside repository
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version of that solution:

```
WCBRANCH=`svn info ${WCDIR} 2> /dev/null | wc -l`
if [ ${WCBRANCH} -eq 0 ]
 then
   echo "Error: directory ${WCDIR} exists and is not part of a working copy."
   exit 1
 fi
```

Comment: If the directory is a working copy of an older SVN version you get a "please upgrade" message after discarding standard error, but ${WCBRANCH} is still 0. Does that apply to all messages the SVN client can issue? To me that sounds risky.